# Visual Studio Type Script Project blocked by group policy

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, security, group-policy

I'm trying to start a simple hello world application on Visual Studio.
[image]

if I start VS as admin it starts like it should.

Because the group policy is not working if I'm admin.

I'm only allowed to execute scripts located in C:\ALLOWED.

```
Build started at 17:35...
1>------ Build started: Project: NodeConsoleApp18, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Build started 19.02.2024 17:35:08.
1>Target RunNpmInstall:
1>  Skipping target "RunNpmInstall" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>Target CoreCompile:
1>  > nodeconsoleapp18@1.0.0 build
1>  > tsc --build
1>
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.92
2>------ Deploy started: Project: NodeConsoleApp18, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Starting deployment of project 'C:\ALLOWED\_work\_TMP\NodeConsoleApp18\NodeConsoleApp18.esproj'...
2>Launching the following configuration from launch.json:
2>
2>Deployment of project 'C:\ALLOWED\_work\_TMP\NodeConsoleApp18\NodeConsoleApp18.esproj' failed. Unsupported launch type(s) specified in launch.json: node
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 17:35 and took 01,069 seconds ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy completed at 17:35 and took 01,069 seconds ==========
```

If I'm running it not as an admin then I get this error.

[image]

```
1>------ Build started: Project: NodeConsoleApp18, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Build started 19.02.2024 17:37:44.
1>Target RunNpmInstall:
1>  Skipping target "RunNpmInstall" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>Target CoreCompile:
1>  Dieses Programm wurde durch eine Gruppenrichtlinie geblockt. Wenden Sie sich an den Systemadministrator, um weitere Informationen zu erhalten.
1>  C:\ALLOWED\.nuget\microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk\0.5.271090-alpha\Sdk\Sdk.targets(172,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.
1>Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "NodeConsoleApp18.esproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "NodeConsoleApp18.esproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>C:\ALLOWED\.nuget\microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk\0.5.271090-alpha\Sdk\Sdk.targets(172,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.
```

I found this here in the detailed view

```
Target CoreCompile:
1>  Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>  Task "Exec"
1>    npm run build
1>    Dieses Programm wurde durch eine Gruppenrichtlinie geblockt. Wenden Sie sich an den Systemadministrator, um weitere Informationen zu erhalten.
1>    C:\ALLOWED\.nuget\microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk\0.5.271090-alpha\Sdk\Sdk.targets(172,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.
1>  Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "NodeConsoleApp18.esproj" -- FAILED.
```

Like you can see everything I could move is moved into C:\ALLOWED but the application still don't build.
I have no idea anymore and would be happy if somebody can give an advice